# I cant post com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: java, android, xml, android-volley, android-studio-3.0

**I try to only post my php script with this code but I have a Server Error**`like so`

```
private static  final String URL1 = "https://exp.com/appLoc.php";

private void User_Enter(){
    StringRequest strRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL1,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(String response){

                 }
             },
             new Response.ErrorListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             })
             {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                        Map<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String> ();

                        params1.put ("location",la+","+lo);
                        params1.put ("licence",shpref.getString (Current_user,null));`like so`
                        params1.put ("main","enter");



                        return params1;
                    }
                };

 queue.add(strRequest1);

}
```

Comment: What is the server error?

Comment: check what is the error message

Answer (score 0):

hi you may have error from server side to decode error what type of error it is use this

```
 public void ShowResponse_Error(VolleyError error, Context context) {

        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {

            Toast.makeText(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.internet_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.timeout_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    context.getString(R.string.auth_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {

            DecodeError(context, error);


        }
    }

 private static void DecodeError(Context context, VolleyError error) {
        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
        try {
            String res = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    obj.getString("message"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // returned data is not JSONObject?
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in String res you will get error.